# How to adjust content of a pre-declared node?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a program that replicates the process of declaring a variable. My approach is creating `Symbol`s with their attributes like type, name, and value. Then I create `SymbolNode`s to store those `Symbol`s, then put those `Node`s into a linked list. So far this is my code:

```
struct Symbol {
    Symbol() : id_name(""), type(""), value("") {}
    Symbol(string id_name, string type, string value, int level) : id_name(id_name), type(type), value(value), level(level) {}

    string id_name;
    string type;
    string value;
    int level;
};

struct SymbolNode {
    SymbolNode() : data(Symbol()), next(NULL) {}
    SymbolNode(Symbol data, SymbolNode* next) : data(data), next(next) {}

    Symbol data;
    SymbolNode* next;
};

class SymbolTable {
public:
    SymbolNode* head;
    SymbolTable() {
        head = NULL;
    }
    void run();
    void insert(Symbol symbol);
    void assign(string id_name, string value);
};

void SymbolTable::insert(Symbol symbol) {

    SymbolNode* node = new SymbolNode(symbol, nullptr);
    SymbolNode* ptr = this->head;
    if (this->head == nullptr) {
        node->next = this->head;
        this->head = node;
    }
    else {
        while (ptr->next != nullptr) ptr = ptr->next;
        ptr->next = node;
    }
}

void SymbolTable::assign(string id_name, string value) {
    SymbolNode* ptr = this->head;
    if (this->head == nullptr) cout << "error" << endl;
    while (ptr != nullptr) {
        if (ptr->data.id_name == id_name) {
            ptr->data.value = value;
            return;
        }
        else {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
void SymbolTable::run() {
    Symbol symbol("x", "number", "", 0);   **//This is like { int x; }**
    insert(symbol);                        **//Putting x into the table**
    assign("x", "15");                     **//Expected to be { x = 15; }**

    Symbol symbol1("y", "string", "", 0);
    insert(symbol1);
    assign("y", "hello mate");
}

int main() {
    SymbolTable* st = new SymbolTable();
    st->run();
    return 0;
}
```

And when I ran the debug step-by-step, it shows that the value of the "number"-type variable named `"x"` is still `""` as default, not `"15"` like I expected. Can anyone help me explain why that happened?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.  [It works when I run your code](https://godbolt.org/z/zT168TcW3).

Comment: @DrewDormann I checked again and somehow the data is there but not displayed during the debugging process, but that's all I need. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).